# 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128) when i add ForeignKey relation in model

Tags: python, django

Sorry for repeated question but any of asked question did not help me so i have ask it again
my models.py

```
class Country(models.Model):
    countryId=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    country=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country

class State(models.Model):
    state_id=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    state=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    countryId=models.ForeignKey(Country,default='000')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.state


class City(models.Model):
    cityid=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state_id=models.ForeignKey(State,default='000')

    # def __unicode__(self):
    #   return u'%s' % self.city

    def __str__(self):
        return ('Proposal for: %s' % self.city).encode('utf8')
```

When i Comment ForeignKey in State,it working fine.
If i use this ForeignKey it throw me an error 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)

```
Unicode error hint

The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: Ãstfol
```

Traceback is

```
File "/home/cpverma/work/school/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/html.py" in <lambda>
  390.         klass.__unicode__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_unicode(self))
File "/home/cpverma/work/school/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in __str__
  537.         return self.as_widget()
File "/home/cpverma/work/school/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in as_widget
  593.         return force_text(widget.render(name, self.value(), attrs=attrs))
File "/home/cpverma/work/school/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py" in render
  292.             'widget': self.widget.render(name, value, *args, **kwargs),
File "/home/cpverma/work/school/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in render
  513.         options = self.render_options(choices, [value])
File "/home/cpverma/work/school/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in render_options
  539.         for option_value, option_label in chain(self.choices, choices):
File "/home/cpverma/work/school/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in __iter__
  1108.                 yield self.choice(obj)
File "/home/cpverma/work/school/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in choice
  1115.         return (self.field.prepare_value(obj), self.field.label_from_instance(obj))
File "/home/cpverma/work/school/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in label_from_instance
  1186.         return smart_text(obj)
File "/home/cpverma/work/school/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py" in smart_text
  56.     return force_text(s, encoding, strings_only, errors)
File "/home/cpverma/work/school/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py" in force_text
  94.                 s = six.text_type(bytes(s), encoding, errors)

Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError at /admin/city/city/49840/
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: When do you get the error? is it when you browse admin? did you change the `state_id` fk in the other model too? do you have any unapplied migrations/ pending migrations?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. It's solved by:

```
return self.state.encode('utf8')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Python 2 (and it seems that you do) you should use `__unicode__` instead of `__str__`, for example:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.state
```

This will solve your problems with encoding.

In Python 3 however `__str__` in the way to go (because the devision between normal strings and unicode strings doesn't exist in Python 3).